# When I add the [map] tag, it is replaced by the [dictionary] tag

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

I was trying to re-tag this question by adding the tag [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map).

[Populating nested C++ map gives incorrect results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962612/populating-nested-c-map-gives-incorrect-results)

But whenever I Edit it, in the Edit page, the tag [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map) is shown
[image]

But after I hit the save button, and view the question, the tag [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) is tagged instead. ( I rolled it back and tried again, but the same issue persists )

So, is this a bug? ( or strangely was this supposed to happen ).

Comment: Should I mark this as a Duplicate of [What are tag synonyms? How do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work)? It's the closest I could find.

Comment: You cannot close it as a duplicate of that one, because it's on a different site. There's no copy on MSO unfortunately.

Comment: map has been mapped to dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map) tag is a synonym of the [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) tag, so it will automatically be replaced.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dictionary/synonyms

> The following tags will be remapped to [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary)
>   [dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dict), [dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionaries), and [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map)

Comment: I feel like an idiot now. Thanks for the answer.